# Swift return bool in method

Tags: swift

I've made this method:

```
func checkScore(player: Int) -> Bool {

        var checkedFields: [Int] = []
        var won: Bool = false

        for var i = 0; i <= 9; i += 1 {

            if(winningCombinations[i] == player) {
                checkedFields.append(i)
            }

        }

        for value in winningCombinations {

            var hits = 0

            for n in checkedFields {

                if value.contains(n){
                    hits += 1
                }

            }

            if hits == 3 {
                won = true
            }

        }

        return won
    }
```

But when I try to build it everything becomes white and the build crashes. Am I doing something wrong here? I pass the value like this:

```
 if self.checkScore(player) {
                print("Won!")
    }
```

(I see no error message!)

Comment: What type is `winningCombinations`? The lines `winningCombinations[i] == player` and `value.contains(n)` don't match.

Comment: Can you provide the contents of winning combination before you call the method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `func checkScore(player: Int)` accepts player, which is of type `Int`.

In your code you also say : `if(winningCombinations[i] == player)`, meaning that you expect the elements in array `winningCombinations` to also be of type `Int`

But then you say

```
for value in winningCombinations {
var hits = 0

            for n in checkedFields {

                if value.contains(n){
```

If value is an element in winningCombination, it means that value is an int.. how can you say value.contains(n). Int cannot perform contains operation. Arrays can.